# VNC/SSH: How to execute a command after logging in?

Tags: ssh, bash, shell, vnc, console

I'm looking for a way to create a VNC console user that executes the command `screen` or `bash` immediately after logging in so they get their own restricted shell for executing commands etc. Screen/bash will be pre-configured to handle all security issues. The VNC console also has to terminate once the user types the exit/logout command as I don't want them to access the rest of the system.

I have already looked through the documentation of TigerVNC and TightVNC but couldn't find anything useful.

If this is not possible with VNC, a SSH console can work as well.

The server's OS is CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

VNC is a tool to provide a Graphical environment to the users.
Using SSH is the way forward for your requirements. If the users BASH environment is already configured with the security restrictions you need, then there should not need to be any further configuration of SSH required.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SSH, the user's shell as specified in `/etc/passwd` will be executed upon login.  Set it to `/bin/bash` and you're done.  You can set this with this command (as root):

```
usermod -s /bin/bash <username>
```